# how to add sql file to import tables to oracle 11g XE

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

i download  .sql file(add_students_table.sql), install oracle 11g XE database and SQL developer, i make connection but how i can add tables from book where i downloaded sql file to import tables so i can follow examples from book...thx

Comment: What book? If you have .SQL files, you can open them in SQL developer, pick a connection, run them with F5. Highly recommend you read the files first and don't touch system and sys accounts

Comment: oracle sql by example, but seems that isn't all tables which i need

Comment: we don't know what you need - instead of making us guess, show us - is there a link for this OBE?

Answer (score 0):

SQL file you downloaded is editable in any text editor, so - open it. What does it contain? There are two options I can think of:

- the first one **creates user** and, afterwards, creates its objects (i.e. runs CREATE TABLE & INSERT INTO statements which populate created tables so that you could practice queries written in the book), or
- there's no CREATE USER (which means that you should create it yourself, connecting as a privileged user - that would be SYS in your XE database, I'd say), but does create tables and inserts data into them

On the other hand, does the book not contain instructions which say what should be done with the SQL file?

Comment: i succed problem with import sql file, looks and work fine, but i did with user SYS, for now i don't have problems or errors.. maybe will be in future.? how i can add other user ?